# Separator for five or more digits number in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, visualization

I was working on a Tableau Project. We want to have a separator for five or more digits numbers.

For ex:-
1 as 1 
12 as 12 
123 as 123 
1234 as 1234 
12345 as 12,345 
123456 as 1,23,456

Can you please assist me, how to achieve this?

Comment: Separator like Indian lakh/crore system?

Comment: in the Indian system, we write 1234 as 1,234. But we want to have a comma separator only for numbers with 5 or more digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am nearly sure that this cannot be done as long as numbers are formatted as numbers.  However, as a workaround, I have developed a method which however will convert numbers to string.  Let's say you have a column `col` of desired numbers

[image]

- copy your column say `col2` (save original for future use) and convery type to `string`
- Create a new calculated field say `desired` by using this calculation

```
If LEN([Col2]) <= 4 THEN
[Col2]
ELSEIF LEN([Col2]) < 6 THEN
REPLACE([Col2], RIGHT([Col2], 3), "") + "," +RIGHT([Col2], 3)
ELSEIF LEN([Col2]) <8 THEN
REPLACE([Col2], RIGHT([Col2], 5), "") + "," + 
REPLACE(RIGHT([Col2],5), RIGHT([Col2], 3), "") + "," +RIGHT([Col2], 3)
ELSE
REPLACE([Col2], RIGHT([Col2], 7), "") + "," + 
REPLACE(RIGHT([Col2],7), RIGHT([Col2], 5), "") + "," +
REPLACE(RIGHT([Col2],5), RIGHT([Col2], 3), "") + "," +RIGHT([Col2], 3)
END
```

- this CF will work exactly as desired for upto 9 digits.

[image]

- Alignment is not a big problem, if considered

[image]